# Recycler item_view height is changing after first initialisation in android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-viewtreeobserver

**In recycler_view adapter class the following code is added for dynamically changing height of item_view**

```
   override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): TaskListViewHolder {
    val itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.task_item_new, parent, false)

    val vto = parentLayer!!.getViewTreeObserver()
    vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(object : ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener {
        override fun onGlobalLayout() {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
                parentLayer!!.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this)
            } else {
                parentLayer!!.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this)
            }
           var quicktaskLayerwidth = parentLayer!!.getMeasuredWidth()
           var quicktaskLayerheight = parentLayer!!.getMeasuredHeight()

            Log.e("Parent_Ht", "" + quicktaskLayerheight/4)
            itemView.getLayoutParams().height = quicktaskLayerheight / 4

        }
    })


    return TaskListViewHolder(itemView)
}
```

In activity class there is a **GridLayoutManager** manager is used for showing **8** icons in recycler_view.

And there is a parent Linear layout, **height** of which is measured in **ViewTreeObserver**

**IMP: At first time recycler_view item height works fine, after loading some other pages and returning to main page the height of item is changing. But the log shows height is calculated and which is correct.**

If someone faced same issue and resolved, need your help here.